# Why shared_from_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?

Tags: c++, constructor, shared-ptr

In [the book *The C++ Standard Library*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215) at page 91 I have read this about `shared_from_this()`:

> The problem is that `shared_ptr` stores itself in a private member of
>   `Person`’s base class, `enable_shared_from_this<>`, **at the end** of
>   the construction of the Person.

The relevant code snippet from the book is:

```
class Person : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Person> {
   ...
};
```

I don't understand two things here:

1. who is this `shared_ptr` which stores itself?
2. how he can store itself anywhere at the end of the construction of `Person`? I think construction of `Person` ends up with the last statement of its constructor which written by me.

I understand that there is `weak_ptr` which hasn't been initialized yet.

EDIT:
Thanks to Angew! `shared_from_this` will work only after first `shared_ptr` to `Person` was created. This `shared_ptr` will check if `Person` class inherited from `enable_shared_from_this`, and if yes then initialize its internal `weak_ptr`.

Comment: I hadn't realized that you were probably just asking for these [Notes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: @MarcoA. Great, these notes really helpful!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The reason is simple: in object `X`, `enable_shared_from_this` works by initialising a hidden `weak_ptr` with a copy of the first `shared_ptr` which points to object `X`. However, for a `shared_ptr` to be able to point to `X`, `X` must already exist (it must be already constructed). Therefore, while the constructor of `X` is running, there is yet no `shared_ptr` which `enable_shared_from_this` could use.

Take this piece of code:

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> p(new Person());
```

Before the constructor of `p` (of the `shared_ptr`) is even called, its argument must be evaluated. That argument is the expression `new Person()`. Therefore, the constructor of `Person` runs before the constructor of `p` has even begun—before there is any `shared_ptr` object to which `enable_shared_from_this` could bind.

Comment: "...`enable_shared_from_this works` by initialising a hidden `weak_ptr` with a copy of the first `shared_ptr` which points to object `X`. "  What procedure is responsible for initializing this hidden `weak_ptr`?  How does it know what the "first" `shared_ptr` that points to `X` is?

Comment: @Chad See the notes here for some information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: Thanks @Holt.  Looks like a constructor of `shared_ptr` is responsible for initializing the `weak_ptr`.  Only those constructors that take a raw pointer (e.g. a pointer returned from a call to new) do the initialization.  Copy constructors don't.  Since only only the first `shared_ptr` to `X` should be constructed from a raw pointer (others are usually copy-constructed), the `weak_ptr` is initialized by the first `shared_ptr` to `X`.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, while the constructor of X is running, there is yet no shared_ptr which enable_shared_from_this could use.

But for the case when make_shared is called it can be possible to access a control block to create a weak_ptr before/while constructor of class working, because they are created in the same allocated memory block with the class.