# Proper way to emplace_back object into std::list

Tags: c++, list, allocation

I have a class with a variety of members (largely ints, floats and some dynamic containers). I have a std::list myclassobjects. In the constructor of this class after setting all of the parameters I call

```
myclassobjects.emplace_back(*this)
```

This works and doesn't appear to cause any issues with allocation; I never have sigsegv issues or similar. However I'm not completely convinced this is the right thing to do, or that it doesn't cause a slow burn memory leak.

Is this method safe to use or does it cause a memory leak? If yes, what's the 'proper' way to go about constructing an object and immediately putting it into a std::list?

Comment: You insert a copy of `*this`. I think you don't want that.

Comment: What you're doing is no different than `myclassobjects.push_back(*this)`. I.e. it creates a *copy* of the current object and appends it to the end of the list.

Comment: typically if you need to keep a set of all constructed objects, you'd store *pointers* to them, or... you'd have a factory/singleton that would make and store them and return a pointer or reference to the created object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `emplace_back` constructs an object in place by forwarding its arguments. So what you end up doing is calling your class's copy constructor with the argument `*this`.

I'm trying to think of a case where adding objects to a list inside the constructor is needed and I'm having a hard time. I think there are better alternatives.

## Emplace it in the list from outside the constructor

Simply create it as follows.

```
myclassobjects.emplace_back(/*constructor params*/);
```

In C++17 this even returns a reference to the newly created object

```
MyClass& myclass_ref = myclassobjects.emplace_back(/*constructor params*/);
do_something_with_my_class_object(myclass_ref);
```

This is the cleanest and most efficient way to do it. It has the added benefit that you can create local objects without adding them to the list if needed.

## Use a factory method that adds it to the list

If you absolutely must have every object in the list and you don't want it to be a copy, use a static factory method. If the list and the callee must share ownership, you can use a list of `std::shared_ptr`s and do the following.

```
MyClass {
private:
    MyClass();    // private constructor forbids on the stack variables

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> create_instance() {
        auto ptr = make_shared<MyClass>();    // We can access the constructor here
        myclass_objects.emplace_back(ptr);
        return ptr;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if your list is guaranteed to outlive the callee's handler on the object, it is more appropriate to have a list of `std::unique_ptr`s that hold the objects and return references to them.

```
MyClass {
private:
    MyClass();    // private constructor forbids on the stack variables

public:
    // pre C++17
    static MyClass& create_instance() {
        auto ptr = make_unique<MyClass>();
        auto& ref = *ptr;    // Store ref before we move pointer
        myclass_objects.emplace_back(std::move(ptr));
        return ref;
    }

    // C++17
    static MyClass& create_instance() {
        auto ptr = make_unique<MyClass>();
        return *(myclass_objects.emplace_back(std::move(ptr)));
    }
}
```

Of course, these examples only cover default constructors. Because you will usually need to work with more constructors, you will probably need a templated `create_instance` that forwards its arguments to the constructor.

Comment: For the first example of calling `emplace_back()`, why did you construct the object in place instead of passing the constructor parameters directly?

Comment: If I don't do it this way, I'll create a local object and push a copy of it in the list. The class might offer a move constructor to make things cheaper, but I've still created an extra object for no reason. With `emplace_back`, the list allocates the space and creates the object directly in this space by forwarding the arguments.

Comment: Right, it makes sense to use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back`(), but why did you call `emplace_back()` the way you did instead of calling it like this: `emplace_back(/* constructor params*/)`?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should have been what you said.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. :)

Comment: Thanks @patatahooligan, this gave me sufficient knowledge and what seems to be the 'proper' way to do this. I went with list.emplace_back(constructor parameters).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to store your object in `std::list` or any other container indeed. An object is a *region of storage*, by the standard definition of object. A region of storage cannot be stored, it just *is*.

Suppose X is an existing object. A container cannot store X itself, but a value related to X in some way. There are two options.

1. Store a *copy* of X.
2. Store a (smart) pointer or a reference wrapper to X.

Since you are emplacing `*this`, you are storing a copy. This may or may not be what you need.

To store a naked pointer, you would have to `emplace_back(this)` and of course change the type of the list. This is dangerous, because when X ceases to exist, your list may still have a dangling pointer to it. You need to make sure it doesn't happen.

You may want to consider storing shared pointers, but if you want to enable it by inheriting `enable_shared_from_this`, be aware that [`shared_from_this` is a dangerous thing to use in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint).