# pass shared_ptr i.e. shared_from_this() as a void*

Tags: c++, c++17

In a C++ class, I am trying to use `shared_ptr`, but instead of using `this` I am trying to use `shared_from_this()`.  In the constructor, I am trying to create an object of a struct which expects a `void*`.  I am not sure how I can convert a `shared_ptr` to a `void*` which can be passed as the parameters to the struct which is expecting `void*`.

Callback.cpp

```
struct CObj{
   int val;
   void* context;    
};

class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>{
private:
  Cobj mCobj;
public:

  A(){
    mCobj = (CObj){5, shared_from_this()};
  }
  ~A(){
  }
  Cobj getObjref(){
    return mCObj;
  }
};

std::shared_ptr p = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A);
Cobj  invokeCfunc = p->getObjref();
```

Comment: Careful with the tagging. You won't be working in all of those version tags at the same time and this definitely isn't C. I removed C and all of the Standard revisions except the most recent. If you'd prefer C++11 or 14, feel free to replace 17.

Comment: As for converting a `shared_ptr` to `void*`, don't. It's not possible without defeating the point of using a shared pointer in the first place. `void` pointers are too simple. They don't even know what they point at, let alone that what they point at has special destruction rules.

Comment: See also ["Why shared_from_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `shared_from_this` in a contructor. You also don't need to because what you wanted was `void*`. `this` implicitly converts to `void*`. You don't need access to the shared pointer in the first place.

This is very simple:

```
A(): mCobj{5, this} {
```

Note that if you make a copy of `A`, then the copy will point to the object it was copied from. Consider whether this is what you want, and if not, then change the copy and move constructor and assignment operator to behave as you would want them to behave.

> I am not sure how can I convert a `shared_ptr` to `void *`

You can use the member function `get`. The resulting pointer implicitly converts to `void*`.