# Enabled shared pointer for base and derived class, also get shared_from_this in constructor of each class?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

There's two issues with this code:

1. Enabling shared from this on class B which is a derived class
2. Calling shared_from_this() in the constructor of each class.

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
      A() {
          shared_from_this();
      }
};

class B : public A, public std::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
public:
      B() {
          shared_from_this();
      }
};
```

Is there to allow both classes to use shared_from_this from their constructors?

Comment: what do you expect from calling `shared_from_this()` while ignoring the retuned value ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It's just an example of using shared_from_this() in the constructor

Comment: is your question how to fix this compiler error: https://godbolt.org/z/qhrfKbnob ?

Comment: you can´t use `shared_from_this` in a constructor even without inheritance

Comment: @Tom, is this an exercise? `shared_from_this` has some very specific uses and the usage in the snippet doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: Please see ["Why shared_from_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924396/why-shared-from-this-cant-be-used-in-constructor-from-technical-standpoint).

Comment: @Zoso No, I generally want to know if this is possible

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes

Comment: if it wasnt `shared_from_this` you would write `std::enable_shared_from_this<B>::shared_from_this();` instead, though as the linked answer explains this is still wrong, maybe UB, I dont know

Comment: it was ub, since  C++17 it throws: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/deEzxh5qe